# thin vertical grey lines in laptop screen

Tags: drivers, graphics, laptop, screen, hp

I need a bit of help, as I'm slowly losing my mind over the following problem. 
I run Xubuntu Linux 16.04 (upgraded recently, not entirely happy with it) on a HP Elitebook 8460p. 
Some two weeks ago, the entire left 3 cm margin of my screen started to display black/green/yellow/blue lines, which seemed to move constantly. Wiggling the screen and pressing here and there solved the problem temporarily, but only temporarily. Furthermore, the next 3 cm seem to be following suit. I ordered a replacement screen from a company here in The Netherlands and got to work. After replacing the screen, and a fresh startup, the screen displays a yellowish sheen, plus that it seems like every second vertical line in the display is "greyed out", making the screen fuzzy and hard to focus on. I thought something was wrong with the replacement screen and send it back, requesting another. The next screen had the same, but with a reddish haze. The next new replacement (the third by now) had a blue-ish haze. All three replacements had the vertical line problem. Placing my old, defect screen back shows a good image, that is, all vertical lines work properly, but for the leftmost 3 cm (that were defect to start with).
I just spoke with one of the guys of the company I bought the replacement screens, and he suggested a graphics driver update and/or a BIOS update. This seems to be logical, as my original screen does work properly. When I look on the HP website for a BIOS update, the Linux BIOS driver is older than the one I am running. As for graphic driver updates, I do not know how to start doing this in Xubuntu. Any ideas and/or leads how to start doing this ?

Update: the tab "Additional Drivers" under "Hardware" in the Settings Manager, shows only an Unknown:Unknown device with the option "Using Processor microcode firmware for Intel CPUs from intel-microcode (proprietary)" checked.

All help is greatly appreciated, many thanks !

Comment: Intel graphics have no official installable drivers, but you could try out [Oibaf's driver](https://launchpad.net/~oibaf/+archive/ubuntu/graphics-drivers).

Comment: @Zacharee1: thanks for the suggestion...just tried it, but to no avail...

Comment: Then your graphics card itself might be on the way out. Try installing Windows. If it's the same problem, it's the computer.

Comment: But with the old, original, but partly defect screen, the thin grey lines are gone. They don't exist until I put in another "new" screen. That is what is weirding me out.

Comment: Do these screens attach directly to the motherboard with a cable, or does the cable stay and the monitor change?

Comment: I am just changing the screens by (dis)connecting a cable that runs from within the computer (didn't open it up further), presumably from the motherboard, to the connector at the bottom of the screen.

Comment: You should open up the computer and make sure the connector on the other end is clean. (Both ends really)